# goquery replace html element with ReplaceWithSelection has not affect

Tags: go, goquery

✌️

I am trying to replace an html parent element with its child elements using "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery". However, ReplaceWithSelection does not replace anything and the selection remains unchanged.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

var html = `
<section>
    <article>
        <h2>Article 1</h2>
        <p>Text for article #1</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Article 2</h2>
        <p>Text for article #2</p>
    </article>
</section>
`

func main() {
    qHtml, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(html))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    section := qHtml.Find(`section`)
    sectionChildren := section.Children().Clone()
    section.ReplaceWithSelection(sectionChildren)

    goquery.Render(os.Stdout, section)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `section` just references one of the children in actual `Document` on which we are using [`ReplaceWithSelection`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.ReplaceWithSelection) the changes will be reflected in actual Document instead of reference which may have be replaced from actual `Document` but since you have the reference still you are to view it with the actual changes.

To view the changes instead of using `section` use `Document` on which the changes are done.

**Change**

```golang
goquery.Render(os.Stdout, section)
```

**To**

```
goquery.Render(os.Stdout, qHtml.Contents())
```